# Найти максимум по полю

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class LogTime
{
    public uint TotalMs { get; protected set; }
    // и другие
}

LogTime GetMax(List<LogTime> Times)
{
    if (Times == null) return null;
    LogTime logMax = Times[0]
    foreach (var t in Times)
    {
        if( t.TotalMs > logMax.TotalMs)
            logMax = t;
    }
    retutn logMax;
}
```

Как сделать ф-цию красивее?

Comment: `LogTime` - это что? или это просто опечатка и это на самом деле `LogError`?

Comment: это пользовательский класс, опечатки нет

Comment: Да хоть пользовательский. хоть нет - какая разница, из кода не понять что такое LogTime, что за переменная Max (logMax?). Код оформлен плохо. Минус вам за оформление вопроса.

Comment: опечатку увидел=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключите [NuGet-пакет `morelinq`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/), тогда можно будет написать так:

```
LogTime GetMax(List<LogTime> Times) => Times?.MaxBy(t => t.TotalMs);
```

[`MoreEnumerable.MaxBy`](https://morelinq.github.io/2.10/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_MaxBy__2.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться методом [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb549218(v=vs.110).aspx), это позволит свернуть последовательность в один элемент:

```
LogTime GetMax(List<LogTime> Times)
{
    return Times?.Aggregate(Times.FirstOrDefault(), (a, b) => a.TotalMs > b.TotalMs ? a : b);
}
```

Также можно сделать более общее решение, напоминающее `.MaxBy`, для этого нужно сделать данную функцию расширением для `IEnumerable<T>`

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static T GetMax<T, TProp>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TProp> fun) where TProp : IComparable<TProp> => source.Any() ? source.Aggregate(source.FirstOrDefault(), (a, b) => fun(a).CompareTo(fun(b)) > 0 ? a : b) : default;
}
```

Тогда ее можно будет вызывать аналогично соседнему ответу:

```
Times.GetMax(t => t.TotalMs)
```

Comment: С `IEnumerable<T>` в общем случае может не прокатить, т.к. вы проходите последовательность несколько раз

Comment: @АндрейNOP, это да, но если предположить, что последовательность **должна быть НЕ пустой**, то все упрощается до `source.Aggregate((a, b) => fun(a).CompareTo(fun(b)) > 0 ? a : b)` и остается один проход :-)

Comment: Ну так давайте же ее сделаем не пустой! [`Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, не, так не пройдет, потому что просто default для класса вернет `null` и все упадет на селекторе свойства, а создавать объект самому не совсем правильно, потому что неизвестно что именно может быть в конструкторе.

Comment: Селектор свойства ни разу не вызовется, поэтому вернется `null`. Ну и `.Any()` надо выбросить и использовать элвис-оператор. Итого получается вот что: `public static T GetMax<T, TProp>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TProp> fun) where T : class where TProp : IComparable<TProp> => source?.DefaultIfEmpty().Aggregate((a, b) => fun(a).CompareTo(fun(b)) > 0 ? a : b);` Правда пришлось ограничить T. https://ideone.com/GWSE7J

Comment: @АндрейNOP, у меня падало с NRE, не помню уже как проверял