# Ошибка при использовании Max в linq

Tags: c#, linq

Скажите пожалуйста, почему компилятор выдает ошибку

> System.ArgumentException: По крайней мере в одном объекте должен быть реализован интерфейс IComparable.

При использовании Max в данном коде (Необходимо найти индекс максимального по модулю элемента массива):

```
int[] mass = {-4,2,7,-2,-3,-6,3,-9,5};
Console.WriteLine(mass.Select((x, y) => new { val = Math.Abs(x), ind = y }).Max().ind);
```

В таком виде все работает нормально:

```
Console.WriteLine(mass.Select((x, y) => new { val = Math.Abs(x), ind = y }).OrderBy(x => x.val).Last().ind);
```

Comment: Внутри max укажите по чему cчитать max...val или index... И используйте уже тогда keyvaluepair

Comment: как ты определяешь какой из объектов с `new { val, ind }` больше?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Найти максимум по полю](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/778727/186999)

Comment: @Grundy похоже, что никак. Если указать в Max(x => x.val), то индекс взять не получается.